# which database driver used by oracle form server 11gr2

Tags: linux, database, jdbc, oracle11g, oracle-fusion-middleware

I am new in field of oracle forms, does any one tel me how oracle forms server connect through database ? does it use any database driver ? if yes than how can we change that ojdbc or jdbc driver?

Right now I am working with oracle forms and report server 11gr2 and database oracle 11g. 
At time of troubleshooting I have deleted following jar file .

- WL_HOME/server/lib/ojdbc6.jar
- omh/oracle_common/modules/oracle.jdbc_11.1.1/ojdbc6dms.jar

as per [oracle](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E12839_01/web.1111/e13737/third_party_drivers.htm) document, which say that weblogic user this JDBC driver to connect with database but after deleting this jar I am still able to connect with database.

Please some one tell how oracle forms and report server connect with database?

Comment: You must have some kind of driver in your lib which you may not be aware of.

Answer (score 1):

Is oracle running under its own user account? If so simply restrict access to the unixodbc packages to the user account, and that should shut down access. You also could firewall the port for that user account, and/or the WebLogic executable if its crucial for you to prevent WebLogic from connecting.